# Symfony Command test create a file in the wrong place

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have a Symfony command that deletes an Entity file and re-generate it with new info from another database. The issue is that the test deletes the file and create it again but under the `test` directory.

I suppose since it is a test it should not delete project files (mock or create a dummy one)

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function test_command()
{
    $kernel = static::createKernel();
    $kernel->boot();

    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->add(new MyCommand());

    $command = $application->find('my:command');

    $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
    $commandTester->execute(
        [
            'command' => $command->getName(),
        ]
    );
    $statusCode = $commandTester->getStatusCode();
    $this->assertEquals(0, $statusCode);
}
```

Any idea to avoid the test to delete files as if it were executed in "production"

Thanks in advance

UPDATE 1:

This is the code of the command. The `generateEntity()` method is who delete the table and create the new one (running the test in the wrong folder as I said)

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->logger->info(sprintf('Starting job "%s"', $this->getName()));

    try {
        $changesDone = $this->importService->importQuestionsAndChoices();

        if ($changesDone) {
            if (!$input->getOption('no-profile-generation')) {
                $this->logger->info('Questions have changed. Re-generating table');
                $this->profileGenerator->generateEntity();
            }
        } else {
            $this->logger->info('No new questions or choices available');
        }
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $this->logger->error($exception->getMessage(), ['exception' => $exception]);
    }

    $this->logger->info(sprintf('Ending job "%s"', $this->getName()));
}
```

Comment: Your code does not seem relevant to me. How do you generate the file inside the command?

Comment: As @goto said, you have to show us the source code of the class `MyCommand`.

Comment: Edited question with the code.

Comment: Arf. The command is just a wrapper around the `generateEntity` method. We need to know how the filepath is determined. Is it from environment variable, from a configuration file, or is it hardcoded ?

Comment: Ok, thanks to your comments I realized that the error is in the path to store the Entity, since It is set within the path who execute the command, so in this case, test/

Thanks!